# Nginx reverse proxy with letsencrypt stopped working and I can't tell why

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, nginx-config, certbot

I am hosting a webapp on Debian, exposed on port 8443. I'm using letsencrypt certificates for SSL (via certbot), and the webapp works fine when I connect to https://example.com:8443.

To allow connection through https://example.com I've used nginx as a reverse proxy, and it worked fine for years. However, during the last month something happened where this no longer functions. Is my configuration no longer valid?

Here's my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/;
            proxy_redirect http://localhost:8443/ https://localhost:8443/;
    }
   
    error_page 502 /502.html;
   
    location /502.html {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell the redirect in the first server block still works, but port 443 just won't hit my webapp.

I've tried adding the following line, as well as reinstalling certbot, to no avail.

```
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
```

I can see no errors when doing `journalctl -u nginx -e -f`, nginx seems to run fine.

When trying to connect to https://example.com I get a connection timed out-error both in browser and with curl.

I'm at my wits end, any help or ideas for debugging are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Maybe your port 443 is firewalled? Please provide more details on "something happened where this no longer functions". Try to debug with ```curl -sv https://example.com```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Doing `curl -sv https://example.com` yields [this](https://pastebin.com/xCrAipUu).

I'm using ufw for firewall, and I've made a rule to allow 443. Doing `ufw status` yields [this](https://pastebin.com/fkz9AQtg).

Comment: It cannot connect to 443, have you tried to restart the service and check the logs - error.log for example, it is located at ```/var/log/nginx```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors in `error.log` and also nothing in `access.log` when I try to access https://example.com (https), but curling http://example.com (http) leaves the following in access.log: `11.111.111.11 - - [10/Aug/2022:22:23:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "curl/7.64.0"`

Comment: do a ```curl -sv https...``` to https and not http, in logs there are redirect 301 to https, which is not available

Comment: I tried `curl -sv https://example.com`, and that leaves no trace in the logs. The output is [here](https://pastebin.com/xCrAipUu)

Comment: ```connect to 11.111.111.11 port 443 failed: Connection timed out``` - the server is not listening at 443, have you tried to restart nginx?

Comment: Yes I have tried both restarting nginx as well as reinstalling.

Comment: Doing a `netstat -anop | grep LISTEN | grep nginx` yields the [this output](https://pastebin.com/FpLfsZnh), so it seems nginx is trying to listen to port 443.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had an iptable rule to redirect 443 to 8080. I found out by doing `iptables -L -n -t nat`.

Thank you Telinov Dmitri for helping me debug the problem.